# Split first and last name Netezza

Tags: netezza

I have a column that has a customer's first and last name separated by a space. What code would I write to parse the two of them? I tried this, but it isn't working.

```
SELECT LEFT (CUSTOMER_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', CUSTOMER_NAME)) as CUST_1ST_1_NM,
substring(CUSTOMER_NAME,  CHARINDEX(' ', CUSTOMER_NAME)+1, len(CUSTOMER_NAME)-(CHARINDEX(' ', CUSTOMER_NAME)-1)) as CUST_LAST_1_NM
from CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using INSTR and SUBSTR like this is the first method that springs to mind.

```
select * from test_table;
 CUSTOMER_NAME
---------------
 foo bar
(1 row)

select substr(CUSTOMER_NAME, 0, instr(CUSTOMER_NAME, ' ')) first_name,
substr(CUSTOMER_NAME,instr(CUSTOMER_NAME, ' ') +1)   last_name
from test_table;
 FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
------------+-----------
 foo        | bar
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use UDFs in Netezza

```
select SQLTOOLKIT..GET_VALUE_VARCHAR( SQLTOOLKIT..ARRAY_SPLIT(CUSTOMER_NAME,' '), 1) as first_name, SQLTOOLKIT..GET_VALUE_VARCHAR( SQLTOOLKIT..ARRAY_SPLIT(CUSTOMER_NAME,' '), 2) as last_name from test_table;
```

OR

```
select SQLTOOLKIT..REGEXP_EXTRACT(CUSTOMER_NAME, '^[^ ]*') as first_name,TRIM(SQLTOOLKIT..REGEXP_EXTRACT(CUSTOMER_NAME, ' .*$')) as last_name from test_table;
```